# Redux-forms undefined is not a function when using validators on react-native (android)

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, redux-form

Im using redux-forms inside my react-native project.
Everything is working great so far, but i'm getting this strange error when adding a validator only under android(see image below)

The component it self is a [react-native-elements](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-elements) input component wrapped inside my custom component(TextFieldInput)

Heres my code for my redux-form input and its validator

Input

```
<Field 
     name="username"
     autoCapitalize='none'
     returnKeyType="next" 
     component={TextFieldInput}
     validate={[ validator.required('Username is required') ]}
 />
```

Heres my simple validator

```
export const required = message => value => value ? undefined : message
```

The error message :

`undefined is not a function (evaluating 'toArray(validators)[typeof Symbol==='function'? Symbol.iterator:'@@iterator']()')`

[image: Image of the error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its caused by missing pollyfils on certain device runtime as far as i can tell.[More info here](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-runtime/)

I managed to fix it by importing :

```
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
```

Inside index.android.js

all you have to do is to add core-js inside your package.json and npm install or yarn.

[Thanks to this github issue](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/2381)